# React Native adding border to PNG

Tags: reactjs, react-native, png

For some reason React Native is displaying the below left and right border when I run my application on iOS (Android is fine).
As you can see on the second image, the logo doesn't have any borders at all.

Do you know where it could be coming from?

```
export const Logo = styled.Image`
  align-self: center;
`;

<Logo source={require('../../assets/logo.png')} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add `elevation:0` to solve it on Android, and add `shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 }, shadowOpacity: 0, shadowRadius: 0` to fix it on IOS, like as follow:

```js
export const Logo = styled.Image`
  align-self: center;
`;

<Logo 
    source={require('../../assets/logo.png')} 
    style={{
        width: 200, 
        height: 200, 
        elevation: 0, 
        shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 }, 
        shadowOpacity: 0, 
        shadowRadius: 0
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: Apparently it looks like it is a bug in the simulator.. when running the App on my physical device it does not occur.. but thanks anyway, your answer lead me to figuring it out! Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Maybe mark as accepted answer? :)